# How to change visibility of a particular layer category in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, table-of-contents, categorized-renderer

I've got one layer with its symbol MARKER, categorized by an expression in 4 colors. The colors depends on a value of a column. So from the TOC, I'm able to click and enable/disable, as they were different layers, and show one category a time.

From python script, I want to do the same, with a loop: show/hide in the map the different existing categories one each time (for printing separated the 4 jpg),

I tried to show the active layers, and categories aren't not showing as a proper layer. So, I thought that the proper layer was a group tree, but when I ask for **QgsLayerTreeGroup** always show no group.

**How can I obtain categories for changing their visibility in the map?**

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
       print "- group: " + child.name()
        if child.name() == "rara": #to check subgroups within test group
            print "rara"
            for subChild in child.children():
                print "child"
                if isinstance(subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                    subChild.name()
    else:
        print "no group: " + root.name()
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `layer` is your `QgsVectorLayer`, you can access layer legend nodes in this way:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
ltl = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer( layer.id() )
ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
legendNodes = ltm.layerLegendNodes( ltl )
```

Now you can make a particular category invisible (e.g., 'cat_A'):

```
legendNode = [ln for ln in legendNodes if ln.data( Qt.DisplayRole ) == 'cat_A']
if legendNode:
    legendNode[0].setData( Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole )
```

---

Alternatively, you could do the following to achieve the same result:

```
ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
lsi = layer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()
ruleKey = [l.ruleKey() for l in lsi if l.label() == "cat_A"]
if ruleKey:
    ltm.findLegendNode( layer.id(), ruleKey[0] ).setData( Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole )
```

Answer (score 1):

To control the visibility of the individual categories:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("culture")[0]
old_renderer = layer.renderer()
new_renderer = old_renderer.clone()

cats = [c for c in new_renderer.categories()] #List all categories
print(cats[0])
#<QgsRendererCategory: 2511 (2511)>

print([m for m in dir(cats[0]) if "_" not in m]) #What can you do with a render category?
#['dump', 'label', 'renderState', 'setLabel', 'setRenderState', 
    #'setSymbol', 'setValue', 'swap', 'symbol', 'toSld', 'value']

#I want to only display objekttypnr=2511
new_renderer.deleteAllCategories() #Delete all categories

#Modify each categories visibility and add them to the new renderer
for cat in cats:
    if cat.value() != 2511: #If it is another value
        cat.setRenderState(False) #Uncheck it
    new_renderer.addCategory(cat)

layer.setRenderer(new_renderer) #Apply the new renderer
```

[image]