# Figuring out whether a feature is visible or not in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, visibility

I have a vector layer (lines) with a numeric (integer) attribute, let's call it `Status`. This layer is styled according to the attribute using a categorized style:

[image: Categorized style]

So far, so good. Now I'm trying to figure out a way to get the *visibility status* (i.e., I click the checkbox on the left) of a feature in this layer using pyqgis. Here's what I have so far:

- It's possible to get the individual `QgsRendererCategoryV2` instances by using `layer.rendererV2().categories()`. This categories, however, don't seem to contain the visibility information, but only the values and colors (or I'm missing something).
- The individiual symbols (e.g. with `layer.rendererV2().symbols()`) don't help me either.

Ideally I would like a solution like `feature.isCurrentlyVisible()`, but I'm prepared to having to look up the attribute in the table myself.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to change visibility of a particular layer category in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247810/how-to-change-visibility-of-a-particular-layer-category-in-pyqgis)

Comment: Yes, this might help... I'll take a look and see what I can do, thanks!

Comment: This leads to another question here: [Can I rely on the order of layer categories in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250749/can-i-rely-on-the-order-of-layer-categories-in-pyqgis)