# Relying on order of layer categories in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, vector-layer, categorized-renderer

Follow-up to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250719/figuring-out-whether-a-feature-is-visible-or-not-in-pyqgis), after input considering [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247810/how-to-change-visibility-of-a-particular-layer-category-in-pyqgis):

To figure out which feature in a QGis vector layer, styled with a categorized renderer, is currently visible (i.e. enabled), I need to

a) Get the value of each category, e.g. with

`print [cat.value() for cat in layer.rendererV2().categories()]`

`--> [u'', u'1', u'9']`

b) Get the status of the checkbox, e.g. with

```
ltl = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer( layer.id() )
ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
legendNodes = ltm.layerLegendNodes( ltl )
print [node.data(Qt.CheckStateRole) for node in legendNodes]
```

`--> [2, 0, 2]`

So far, so good. Can I rely on the order of those two being the same or do I have to do some sort of cross-checking (and if so, any ideas how? The `symbol` instances that I can access through both paths don't seem to match...)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the value,, you could match the legend name with its checkstate:

```
legend_names = [node.data(Qt.DisplayRole) for node in legendNodes]
legend_state = [node.data(Qt.CheckStateRole) for node in legendNodes]

[a for b in zip(legend_names,legend_state) for a in b]
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]

Code used:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

layer = iface.activeLayer()
ltl = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer( layer.id() )
ltm = iface.layerTreeView().model()
legendNodes = ltm.layerLegendNodes( ltl )

legend_names = [node.data(Qt.DisplayRole) for node in legendNodes]
legend_state = [node.data(Qt.CheckStateRole) for node in legendNodes]

[a for b in zip(legend_names,legend_state) for a in b]
```

Comment: Good suggestion! Still, I'd rather not do this association via strings, especially since the labels might be the same for two categories.

Comment: @LuWi - Good point! I think you may be right in that the order of the legend nodes are read sequentially (i.e. the values and the checkbox state seem to match).